# MATLAB compilation

Tags: matlab, compilation

I'm try to compile a matlab project on RHEL 7.6,
Whene I try to run the follow command:

```
mcc -m SliceViewerMain.m -a <PATH>/*.fig -a <PATH>/*.bmp -a <PATH>/*.m
```

I get this error:

```
Error: You specified the file "<PATH>/pause_e.bmp" without using the "-a" option.
```

Is anyone know why I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify, but I suspect you're using `mcc` at the shell command-prompt, rather than in MATLAB? In which case, the shell is expanding the `*` wildcard before `mcc` gets to see it, so it's as if you said:

```
$ mcc ... -a <PATH>/pause_a.bmp <PATH>/pause_b.bmp <PATH>/pause_c.bmp ...
```

The fix is either run the command inside MATLAB, or hide the wildcard expansion from the shell and let `mcc` expand by doing

```
$ mcc ... -a '<PATH>/*.fig' ...
```

I.e. use single quotes.